# Receive json array to PHP

Tags: php, android, json

im passing json array as follows in android. Here is the code below

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", request_tag));

    if(data.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("iscomplete[]",data.getString(0)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uidUser[]",data.getString(1)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("connectID[]",data.getString(2)));
        }while(data.moveToNext());
    }
response = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(requestUrl, params);
    Toast.makeText(context, response, 10000).show();
```

now i want to receive it on server side bt it wont work on php

```
if ($tag ==  'request')
{
    $complete = (array)$_POST['iscomplete[]'];
    $uiuser = (array)$_POST['uidUser[]'];
    $connectId = (array)$_POST['connectID[]'];
               echo $complete//This gives a blank value
}
```

json code is as follows

```
public String getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        response=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        Log.d("Response",response);
        //jObj=new JSONObject(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


    return response;

}
```

On echoing the toast i get an empty message. I think i have not received the data properly

Comment: Can you show us the JSON?

Comment: `$local_array_of_object = json_decode($POST['incomingjsonarray']);`

Comment: @Daan added new code.

Comment: Try $_POST['iscomplete'].  If that doesn't work, dump out the content post with a var_dump($_POST) to see what's actually being passed.

Comment: Brilliant :)  I'll create it as a proper answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your Android app, you're creating the iscomplete, uidUser and connectID param's as arrays by giving them square brackets after the name declaration.

When PHP interprets a page, it converts all parameters (be it from POST or GET) into their array based equivalents.  So

```
?iscomplete[]=one&uidUser=23&connectID=3432
```

will become:

```
$_POST['iscomplete'] = array('one');
$_POST['uidUser'] = array(23);
$_POST['connectID'] = array(3432);
```

When you want to get the value, you don't need to include the square brackets - PHP has already stripped them.  So you just need:

```
if ($tag ==  'request')
{
    $complete = (array)$_POST['iscomplete'];
    $uiuser = (array)$_POST['uidUser'];
    $connectId = (array)$_POST['connectID'];
    echo $complete;
}
```